# ReadProcessMemory() doesn't works with long address like 0x2840C6C68D8

Tags: c++

I am trying to read values from a game with `ReadProcessMemory()` but it seems like i can only use that with short addresses. I was successful reading values with exact same code but a game that has shorter addresses. Like this `0x5CD38994` However when i try to do same thing with a different game that has longer addresses like `0x2840C6C68D8` i just get 0. I think it's about ReadProcessMemory() What should i do?

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle,(LPVOID)0x2840C6C68D8, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0);
```

```
Entire Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

DWORD pid;
int my_value;

int main(){

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("game"));

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    std::cout << pid << std::endl;
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    while(1){
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x2840C6C68D8, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0);
        std::cout << my_value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code.

Comment: This post should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690525/readprocessmemory-with-int64-address

Comment: @Geno-c i have posted the entire code

Comment: What is your project build in?

Comment: @Geno-c I am using Eclipse IDE and GCC compiler

Comment: Are you compiling this code for 32bit or 64bit? `0x2840C6C68D8` is not valid to use if compiling in 32bit, as it will exceed the size of a 32bit `void*` pointer, but `0x5CD38994` will not. If you want to access data in a remote 64bit process, your code should be compiled for 64bit as well.

Comment: @Lebeau my machine is 64bit. But i don't know if i am compiling it for 32bit or 64bit. How can i learn that and how to compile it for 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You must compile for x64 by using `gcc -m64', otherwise you cannot use ReadProcessMemory() to read 64bit addresses.